# Extending the native library of codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

How can i extend the codeigniter form validation native library and add additional more paramater to the existing function, for example the existing set_rules function accept 3parameter meanss how can i modify the set_rules function accept 4parameter, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Follow this : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html#extending-native-libraries

Comment: FYI, `set_rules` already accepts four parameters. [See Docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#CI_Form_validation::set_rules) The fourth being an array of error messages. The link @Rijin gave you shows you how to extend the core library. You might get other suggestions if you would explain what you want to achieve.